# BroadcastReceiver instead of Activity

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-manifest

I have an application that doesn't have any activities. All it does is show a notification. Is it possible to put launcher filter on the BroadcastReceiver instead of the main activity?

Here is what I've tried:

```
<receiver android:name=".LaunchReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

It doesn't work. The app installs, but there is no icon in the launcher.

If it's not possible, are there any other ways to not show the activity? Currently I just have an empty activity and call `finish()` from `onCreate()`, but the it still shows up for a split second, which doesn't look nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [Receiver](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/receiver-element.html) receives broadcasts only. Only an activity belongs in the launcher. [Intents and filters](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html) explains much of this.

To make an invisible activity (to not see it while you quickly finish() it) declare it with this theme:

```
@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar
```

But you better also add the following if you have an invisible activity (to avoid confusing the user):

```
android:noHistory="true"
```